# How to properly make Rails routes with multiple optional segments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

While working on Rails 4 applications, I have stumbled over the following issue multiple times:

Say I have a model, `Task`.

- A task can have a varying status, e.g. `open`, `in progress` or `closed`.
- A task can have a varying priority, e.g. `normal`, `high`, `critical`.

Now, I want to show a list of tasks for each of these possibilities. Therefore, in my Routes file, I create the following:

```
resources :tasks do
  get "status/:status", action: :index, on: :collection, as: :status_list
  get "priority/:priority", action: :index, on: :collection, as: :priority_list
end
```

The `index` action checks if the `params[:status]` is present, and if so, filters the tasks collection to only use those with the given status. It also checks for the `tag` parameter, and filters the tasks collection to only the ones with the given priority.

However, I would like to combine these two ways of filtering (in a way that does not use GET-parameters).

This is what I tried:

```
resources :tasks do
  get "list/(:status/(:priority))", action: :index, on: :collection, as: :list
end
```

This has the following problem, however: When attempting to use the path helper with only a priority, e.g. when calling `list_tasks_path(priority: :high)`, the resulting URL reverts to `tasks/list`, as there is a missing URL segment.

This problem might be mitigated by also adding a route for the situation with just a priority, but then I need to put an if-statement in my views every time I want to make a link to switch between the two.

How is this resolved properly? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: In my opinion, you are having your routes do more than they should do.  I would only have one single route for `GET`ing Tasks, and have the logic for filtering done in your controllers

Comment: When you say 'in a way that does not use GET-parameters' you are saying you don't wanna make it restful?

Comment: @CristianoAlencar: I would presume it would be more REST-ful, as as far as I know a path like `/tasks/list/open/high` nests in a way that `/tasks?status=open&priority=high`, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the path as follows:

```
get "list/(:priority)/(:status)", action: :index, on: :collection, as: :list
```

Here `list_tasks_path(priority: :high)` will return you the correct path [/tasks/list/high] and `params[:status]` would be `null`